# XPath strict contains() function

Tags: xpath

I'm using xpath's contains function to find elements that contain some text, like this:

```
//td[contains(text(),'foo')]
```

But if the page, for example, contains two `td` elements, that contain `foo` and `foo bar` respectively, the above xpath will return both of them.
Is there any kind of strict `contains`, that will return only the element with text `foo`, but not the one with `foo bar`?

Comment: you mean **td** has **<td>foo</td>** and **<td>foo bar</td>** OR it has **<td>some text is foo and other soon</td>** something like this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By "strict contains" do you actually mean a simple **equality** test?  If so you should be able to do that using `//td[text() = 'foo']`.

Comment: I would even drop the `text()` and simply do `//td[. = 'foo']`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:-

```
//td[normalize-space() = 'foo']
```